# Using FormBuilder to highlight a pristine but invalid form

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Using `FormBuilder` in Angular 2 to highlight dirty and invalid fields is easy. However, you can submit a pristine but invalid form without ever changing the fields to dirty.

For example, this code will show that when you submit the form without ever touching the inputs the `FormGroup` will be invalid but `.ng-pristine` will remain on the text field. This means that the user will not be notified that something is wrong with the text field.

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
      <input type="text" formGroupName="foo">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
    </form>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .ng-dirty.ng-invalid { border: 2px solid red; }
  `]
})

export class AppComponent {
  public myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myFormGroup = this._fb.group({
      foo: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    console.info('is the form pristine?', this.myFormGroup.pristine);
    console.info('is the form valid?', this.myFormGroup.valid);
  }
}
```

Example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6Uq39aqKgdmRSzcjBSv?p=preview).

How can you change a pristine `FormControl` to dirty when submitting a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function `.markAsDirty()` on anything that implements the `AbstractControl` interface. So, in your onSumbit():

```
public onSubmit(): void {
    this.myFormGroup.markAsDirty();
    console.info('is the form pristine?', this.myFormGroup.pristine);
    console.info('is the form valid?', this.myFormGroup.valid)
}
```

Forked plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k8iXCLyKIIm8QN1wgMVg?p=preview